# How to pass data from View to Controller when data is set by JavaScript?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a span whose value is set via knockout.js:

```
<span id="total" data-bind="text: total"></span>
```

This is setted whenever a slider changes value. All of this is inside a BeginForm. Now my problem is how do I get this to be passed (via model binding) to the controller. How do I get this value inside the model on submit so it can be binded when I call an Action?

**EDIT:**

Ok, let me rephrase my question. I have cshtml file which is strongly-typed to a model. Now a property of this model (Total) is bound to a hidden field to served as the base value:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Total, new { id = "base-total" })
```

Now in this cshtml, there is a slider in which it changes a span's value to a computation based on the slider and the base total.

```
<span id="total" data-bind="text: total"></span>
```

I need this changed via js as I couldn't have the page reload everytime I move the slider. So my problem now is the display is changed but the actual model value isn't, so when I submit, the model still has the base total value.

How can I have the value that I changed via js be passed on the model? If this is not the correct way, can you suggest what I might try?

Comment: can you please add some more code ?

Comment: `<span>` elements are not form controls so their values do not post back. An option might be to bind a hidden input to the value.

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke - Thanks for the reply, could you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

On way you can do it is to manually send your JS model to the server on submit of your form.

For example:

```
<form data-bind="submit: doSomething">
    ... form contents go here ...
    <span id="total" data-bind="text: total"></span>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        doSomething : function(formElement) {
            // ... now do something

            var data = JSON.stringify(
            {
                total: self.total // for example.
            }); // prepare request data

            $.post("/api/your-service", data, function(response) // sends 'post' request
            {
                // on success callback
                self.responseJSON(response);
            })
        }
    };
</script>
```